# how to trigger observer by rest api

Tags: magento2, event-observer, rest-api

I need to trigger observer whenever I call specific rest api

I've created `module/Observer/ObserverClass`, `module/etc/events.xml` and `module/etc/webapi-rest/events.xml` but I don't know How to trigger it through rest api

how can I do so

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Please check vendor module:
vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule/etc/webapi_rest/events.xml

Also https://mage2.pro/t/topic/137

Answer (score 0):

First initialize webapi

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/hello/name/:name" method="GET">
        <service class="Namespace\Module\Api\HelloInterface" method="name"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Define Interface – etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Namespace\Module\Api\HelloInterface"
                type="Namespace\Module\Model\Hello" />
</config>
```

Dispatch(initialize) custom observer like below in implementing class

```
 $textDisplay = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(array('text' => 'Module'));
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch('namespace_module_display_text', ['mp_text' => $textDisplay]);
```

After this, call this "namespace_module_display_text" events.xml
app/code/Namespace/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="namespace_module_display_text">
        <observer name="new_event" instance="Namespace\Module\Observer\NewEvent" />
    </event>
</config>
```

And call observer class

```
app/code/Namespace/Module/Observer/NewEvent.php
```

write class definition on above class.

Thanks

Comment: I have to dispatch the event in Hello class ?